# run two instance of same app with different config file at same machine is it possible?

Tags: node.js, config

I have a node.js app with a mongodb database so I want to have two instance of an app running at the same time . one on production and one on development. so is it possible to set different NODE_ENV on different instance of an app.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking can be achieved using:

```
NODE_ENV=development node server.js
```

You can run one instance with development and second one with production.

Comment: are env variables per process or per whole platform

Comment: I mean if I change the NODE_ENV to development do it have any affect of NODE_ENV of the first instance of app

Comment: No there would be no effect on the other.

Comment: I am using pm2. and in pm2 config file I should hard the env variable. can you help me on that

Comment: for pm2 you provide environment to run like this `pm2 start app.json --env dev` where app.json is process file

Comment: in pm2 config file I set numberOfApp to run to max how should I manage to run just one instance of app in development and others in production

Comment: As long as I am aware you can run single dev instance first `pm2 start app.js -i 1 --env dev` and then run with production setting it up to max.

Answer (score 0):

Use .env file via .gitignore if you will take a pull in both instances it won't transfer in your instance you will create .env in your project, then it will be different for both projects.

.env file for production

```
db = mongodb://XX.XXX.XX.XX/zXp
IAM_USER_SECRET = 06VXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRzC
NODE_ENV = production
```

.env file for development

```
db = mongodb://XX.XXX.XX.XX/zXp
IAM_USER_SECRET = 06VXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRzC
NODE_ENV = development
```